# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for nuget push command

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy, octopus

I am currently looking into using **Octopus** for our deployments. I'm trying to push the latest .nupkg file to our **Octopus** server as follows.

```
NuGet.exe push outputfolder\My.nupkg -ApiKey myapikey  -Source https://myproject.octopus.app/nuget/packages
```

However I'm getting the following error.

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I've never seen this error before. What causes this error and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I've installed the latest version of **nuget.exe** and this has removed the error message. However I'm now being prompted to enter my username and password when I upload the package to the Octopus server. How do I pass these in via my script?

I am seeing this when I run my script from the commandline.

```
Pushing MyPackage.nupkg to https://MyProject.octopus.app/nuget/packages...

PUT https://MyProject.octopus.app/nuget/packages/

Please provide credentials for https://MyProject.octopus.app/nuget/packages
Username:
```

Answer (score 2):

NuGet.org will remove support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in April, 2020
We realize adapting to change can take time, and we want to share our plans early. To help minimize the number of affected users, we plan to make this change in two stages:

- **February 2020**: Temporarily remove support for TLS 1.0/1.1 in 3 timezones, for 4 hours each, to ensure overlap with normal working hours across the globe
- **April 2020**: Permanently remove support for TLS 1.0/1.1

If you need more about next steps, please refer to [doc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/)

Comment: Thnaks for the info

Comment: Are there any alternative commands I can use in the meantime that will perform the same action? Does the dotnet CLI support this?

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to solve this problem by updating nuget.exe to a newer version (2.8 to 5.0).